# Is there anyway to stream music from an unsupported streaming service to a DLNA enabled amp?

Tags: streaming

I have an amplifier that supports DLNA streaming.  DLNA is not actually supported by the streaming services I use (amazon music, idagio).

There are applications out there that are supposed to bridge the gap between the phone & DLNA supported device, such as BubbleUPnP & mconnect.

However their support is also frustratingly limited.  For example BubbleUPnP does support streaming from TIDAL & Qobuz but that's it.

I am going to give up DLNA solution and move on to something like Chromecast or a dedicated streamer.

However I just want to make sure, is there a way I can stream anything (in an adhoc way) from my phone to my amp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via bluetooth would be one way.
You just need to buy a bluetooth adapter so that you can send the phone output to the amplifier via bluetooth (which I assume it currently does not have.)
There are many on the market. Eg. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B086VZQG55/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_VJGK0VRDQYVXA6GSHQR7?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086VZQG55)
Now, the issue will be that you'll have to have the phone app actually on and doing the work of downloading the song bytes and sending out bluetooth. You cant just 'cast' it to the amplifier like you could with chromecast.
If you have to use chromecast with your beloved amp, you may have to find an HDMI chromecast and then something like this [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B084RN22MW/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_KA6H54059MFRAKE6PK4R?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084RN22MW)  to extract the audio out and feed it to your amplifier. (I haven't tried this.)
There are of course, other amplifiers with chromecast built in...
Wish you all the best !

Comment: Thank you @kalyanswaroop.  I am leaning towards the second option in your answer.  All morning I have been trying to find a splitter that takes in HDMI and outputs a USB digital output.  Do u know of such a splitter?

Comment: I dont know of such a converter that can take HDMI and then output the audio over USB. But there are things that can take 3.5mm audio plug and translate that to USB. Such as https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Headphone-Microphone-Aluminum-Compatible/dp/B00NMXY2MO (I havent used it). Maybe you'll have to chain a HDMI to audio splitter with one of these ! Lots of wires for something wireless !